# Selecting filtered data for whiskers on an errorbar in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

Sample of dataset:

```
sample <- structure(list(NAME = c("WEST YORKSHIRE", "WEST YORKSHIRE", "WEST YORKSHIRE", 
"WEST YORKSHIRE", "WEST YORKSHIRE", "WEST YORKSHIRE", "NOTTINGHAMSHIRE", 
"NOTTINGHAMSHIRE", "NOTTINGHAMSHIRE", "NOTTINGHAMSHIRE", "NOTTINGHAMSHIRE", 
"NOTTINGHAMSHIRE"), ACH_DATE = structure(c(17410, 17410, 17410, 
17440, 17440, 17440, 17410, 17410, 17410, 17440, 17440, 17440
), class = "Date"), MEASURE = c("DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS", "DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS_LL", 
"DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS_UL", "DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS", "DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS_LL", 
"DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS_UL", "DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS", "DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS_LL", 
"DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS_UL", "DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS", "DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS_LL", 
"DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS_UL"), VALUE = c(73.6, 66.2, 79.8, 73.7, 66.3, 
80, 77, 69.1, 83.6, 77.5, 69.6, 84.2)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

I'm trying to visualise the error bars for the points seen here:

```
sample %>% filter(MEASURE == "DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS") %>% ggplot(aes(x=ACH_DATE, y=VALUE, group=ACH_DATE)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", dotsize=0.2)
```

As you can see in the df the lower and upper limits are contained in a variable `MEASURE` with my  point values of interest in a long format.

What I'm stuck is how I can filter the df further, to use the lower and upper limit values in the `ymin` and `ymax` arguments.

I've tried something like:

```
sample %>% filter(MEASURE == "DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS") %>% ggplot(aes(x=ACH_DATE, y=VALUE, group=ACH_DATE)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", dotsize=0.2) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = ACH_DATE,
                    ymin = sample %>% filter(MEASURE == "DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS_LL") %>% select(VALUE),
                    ymax = sample %>% filter(MEASURE == "DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS_UL") %>% select(VALUE)),
                data = sample %>% filter(MEASURE != "DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS"),
                colour="red")
```

Which throws the error: `` Error: Columns `ymin`, `ymax` must be 1d atomic vectors or lists ``. I've tried wrapping my input to the `ymin` and `ymax` arguments with `as.vector`, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Maybe something like `ymin = sample %>% filter(MEASURE == "DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS_LL") %>% min(select(VALUE))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ggplot`, like other `tidyverse` libraries, works with [non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html). It's expecting the bare names of data frame columns in arguments such as `ymin`. What you supplied is instead a data frame with only 1 column: `dplyr::select` returns a data frame/tibble with the given columns, hence the error about needing to supply a vector.

```
sample %>% filter(MEASURE == "DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS_LL") %>% select(VALUE)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 1
#>   VALUE
#>   <dbl>
#> 1  66.2
#> 2  66.3
#> 3  69.1
#> 4  69.6
```

If you really wanted to use this method of having all your types of measures in one column and filtering for different types, `dplyr::pull` takes a single column name and returns the data in that column as a vector.

However, there are multiple concerns you're trying to handle in this data frame that you probably ought to separate. You have observation values (means, medians, or whatever), you have upper confidence interval limits, and you have lower confidence interval limits. While the answer to `ggplot` issues is *often* long-shaping data, this is a case where these are three different concerns that have different places in your plot—therefore, you're better off making them individual columns. You can do this with `tidyr::spread`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

sample %>%
  tidyr::spread(key = MEASURE, value = VALUE)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   NAME     ACH_DATE   DIAG_RATE_65_PL… DIAG_RATE_65_PLU… DIAG_RATE_65_PLU…
#>   <chr>    <date>                <dbl>             <dbl>             <dbl>
#> 1 NOTTING… 2017-09-01             77                69.1              83.6
#> 2 NOTTING… 2017-10-01             77.5              69.6              84.2
#> 3 WEST YO… 2017-09-01             73.6              66.2              79.8
#> 4 WEST YO… 2017-10-01             73.7              66.3              80
```

And then use those separate columns that have separate purposes for the corresponding parts of your geoms.

```r
sample %>%
  tidyr::spread(key = MEASURE, value = VALUE) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = ACH_DATE, y = DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS, group = ACH_DATE)) +
    geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y") +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS_LL, ymax = DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS_UL))
#> `stat_bindot()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-10-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: You're right this is one of the instances where wide data is better than long. My code was getting overly convoluted for what is usually a simple task. Appreciate the longer answer as it helps me learn too.